# does final static automatically employ lazy instantiation?

Tags: c#, java, static, singleton, final

the page at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html?page=5 says that code like this:

```
public final static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
```

automatically employs lazy instantiation.

I want to verify if

1) all compilers do this, or is it that the compiler is free to do whatever it wishes to

2) and since c# does not have the "final" keyword, what's the best way to translate this into c# (and at the same time it should automatically employ lazy instantiation too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The static initializer is guaranteed to run before you are able to access that `INSTANCE`. There are two negatives with this approach:

1. If an error occurs within the Singleton's construction, then the error is a little harder to debug ("Error in initializer").
2. On first use of the class, that object will be instantiated. If you did the locking approach, then it would not be instantiated until it was needed. However, being that the example is a singleton, then this is not a problem *at all*, but it could be a drag on an unused, yet lazily instantiated piece of code elsewhere that is *not* a singleton.

The translation for C# is `readonly` instead of `final`.

In my opinion, this is still vastly preferable to the secondary approach (synchronized/locked, checked instantiation within the a static getter) because it does not require any synchronization code, which is faster, easier to read and just as easy to use.

Comment: heys does the readonly in C# also ensure lazy instantiation? or does the readonly in c# only ensure synchronization?

Comment: Sort of. It depends on the version of the .NET Framework that you are running (pre-4 or 4+). See: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) (this used to be my go to post for C# Singleton patterns; note example number 5). For .NET 4, see [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx) where it _is_ lazily initialized same as Java. To avoid any confusion, use [`Lazy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) in .NET 3.5+. Unfortunately, it's a tricky subject in C#.